# Computer for some reason won't accept requests. Can send requests though. (All on LAN)

Tags: networking, firewall, lan

I'm on a LAN and I've been working forever trying to figure out what in the world is wrong.  After much pain, I've come to this.  I can ping *Computer B* and *Computer B* from *Computer A* but *Computer A* cannot be pinged from any of the other computers.  My Windows firewall doesn't work so it isn't even enabled.  I have no other firewalls currently enabled.

Here is the output of `ipconfig` just in case it's helpful.

```
Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 6:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ncssm.edu
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::48a1:ddb9:f4c5:954f%58
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.130.160
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.128.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.128.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 30:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1EA980F5-3987-410D-8F6B-330E3CC346CF}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2093230A-E697-478F-8BE8-6C7DBACC9BE9}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{26C7DA73-645A-4B66-8512-622670C9FCE7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.nc.rr.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{77549381-A430-4393-833A-1BC2A49DD819}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 32:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

All of the other computers are able to connect just fine.  Feel free to ask me to do stuff to get information for you.  I understand that this will probably be a multi-step process but I can't seem to figure out what step I should take next to fix the issue.

I previously asked this question here:  [Can't Share Folders - "There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper."](https://superuser.com/questions/458168/cant-share-folders-there-are-no-more-endpoints-available-from-the-endpoint-m/459329#comment538539_459329)

File/Directory Sharing works fine now but my Firewall still doesn't work which I figure is still a result of the malware or whatever I was temporarily inconvinced by.

**Process 1**

Alright, so here is what I pretty much get when trying to enable the firewall, etc. etc.

[image]

**Process 2**

After further attempts to fix the firewall, I'm currently left with this:

[image]

Comment: You need to figure out what's wrong with your firewall first. That's a huge variable that you're walking in to blind. Are you sure it's not still enforcing any of its rules? And if it's due to malware then all bets are off, your system could be doing anything.

Comment: @r.tanner.f :: That's very understandable (and somewhat obvious).  At this point, however, I can't really do much about what's happened.  Any suggestions as to how I could start the process of diagnosing my firewall?  Thanks - I've also added a screenshot of what I get when I attempt to modify/edit my firewall.

Comment: Start by figuring out why the firewall service won't start (WFAD?). Which dependency isn't started and what happens when you try to start it?