# Can't connect to shared folders anymore?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-shares

My home server is running Windows Server 2008 R2. I've had it running for almost a year now without any issues with shared folders. This past week I had an issue with my modem which required it to be power cycled and with that I power cycled my router. After that I haven't been able to connect to my shared network folders. I have no idea why that would even cause an issue as I've power cycled my networking equipment in the past without issues and none of my settings appear to have been lost.

I am mapping these drives on my Windows 7 Ultimate machine using "Map Network Drive", from there I enter `\\SERVER\Storage` as I'm trying to connect to my shared folder named Storage.

I receive the following error every time I try mapping the drive:

> Windows cannot access `\\Server\Storage`
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise there might be a problem
>   with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems,
>   click Diagnose.
>
> Details: Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found.

When I click Diagnose I get the following:

> Problems found
>
> file and print sharing resource (SERVER) is online but isn't
>   responding to connection attempts.
>
> The remote computer isn't responding to connection on port 445,
>   possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it
>   might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn't find any problems
>   with the firewall on your computer.

I've tried this from multiple computers with the same issue too.

To resolve the problems so far I've tried:

- Disabling the firewall on SERVER
- Reinstalling File Services
- Modifying NetBT\Parameters registry values
- Adding a custom inbound rule for port 445
- Adding port forwarding on my router for port 445
- Recreating the shared folders
- Checking and rechecking the shared folder permissions.
- Resetting my user account password on the server used to access the shared folder.

I'm pulling my hair out with this problem mainly because it came out of nowhere. It was working fine the night before and the next day it just stopped working. Any ideas of what I could try next are much appreciated.

It should also be noted that this server is used as a web server too and that functionality still works correctly.

Comment: Is your server set to use DHCP for its TCP/IP address or does it have a static address?

Comment: It has a static address for both Ethernet ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/443329/windows-7-file-and-printer-sharing-doesnt-work-for-me) on a similar subject if you have not already.

As for the server side, I would just check all of your security settings in gpedit.msc

However unlikely; It also would not hurt to make sure you are not being affected by MS08-067 RPC vuln, Spoolsvc vuln, or some other *stuxnet-esque* vulnerability. Here is one of many ways to assess such a threat:
http://www.trendmicro.com/ftp/products/pattern/spyware/fixtool/StuxnetScanner.zip

Comment: Server is set to automatic and it's started.

By browser do you mean Computer Browser? That server was disabled but I've since set that automatic and started that too.

Time is 12:49AM 11/2/2013 on my server as it is on my desktop.

What is NTLMv2? Is that a service too or something else?

Comment: Well I'm stupid. My server has 2 network adapters. When I reset my network equipment the other day I must have bumped one of them and it became unplugged. I was still able to remote into my server though so that's why I ruled out the network connection without even checking.

Thanks for the link to that, I opened my Network Connections and finally realized the problem.

..If you need I'll be sobbing in a corner for spending several days trying to troubleshoot such a simple problem, I'm slipping in my old age.