# Windows 7 machine can't access any shared folders

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I have a windows 7 machine which is unable to access the Samba (Linux) file server on the network however it is also unable to access the shares of any other computer on the network. All other computers on the network are able to do both these things.

This machine has had in the past (by accident) been a member of it's own Homegroup however only for about 10 minutes.

I have tried changing *"Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level"* to *"Send LM & NTLM Responses"* to no avail. I have also checked the *"Advanced Sharing settings"* match those of a working machine. The machine is able to access the share in safe mode however this isn't particularly useful to me!
The machine is also able to access the server by FTP (not Samba but same hardware.)
Disabling all firewalls involved (Router, Local, Server) does not help the issue either.

Many thanks for any help it is greatly appreciated as this has well and truly stumped me!

Comment: You can try to change member of: workgroup to something else do a restart and than change back to the actual workgroup you are using on other machines

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have helped. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this happened to me after different tries it seems that where a problem on network device configuration (maybe corrupted by third part software). So I had to uninstall and reinstall "File and Printer..." as seen in the picture.

[image]

If it doesn't work try to uninstall an reinstall the driver of your nic card it will reset this file stack

Comment: you have a detailed discussion here: http://superuser.com/questions/443329/windows-7-file-and-printer-sharing-doesnt-work-for-me/   (cross my mind right now)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give this a go when I can get to the machine probably next week some time. Thanks again!